# Linking 2 check boxes on different page on MFC dialog based application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkbox, mfc, dialog

I have made 1 single dialog with 2 different GUIs and they can be selected by tabs. Each GUI has many check boxes. Some of the check boxes are linked, such that when 1 is checked, the other one will automatically be checked. When the 2 linked check boxes are on the same GUI, I can do it. But when they are on different GUIs, I have problems. Is it possible to link 2 check boxes on different GUIs?

This is how I linked 2 check boxes on the same GUI. When checkbox1 is checked, checkbox2 will also become checked.

```
void ProjectName::OnBnClickedCheckBox1()
{
    bool x = ((CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CheckBox1))->GetCheck();
    ((CButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_CheckBox2))->SetCheck(x);
}
```

But this doesn't work when the other checkbox is on the other GUI.  Is there a way I can call a checkbox (eg. IDC_CheckBox3) which is on another GUI on this GUI's .cpp? Or is there any other way I can do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please define "different GUI". "GUI" is probably not the correct term here, which makes the question a bit unclear.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I assume it is a property sheet with two pages.

Comment: Different dialog? I have 3 dialog in total. The main one are the tabs, and the other 2 are the ones with the check boxes. The main one controls which of the other 2 dialog will be shown.

Comment: You should show your resources for the GUI items and maybe screen shots. You have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters/variables to pass values to another Tab.

for e.g. Tab1 -> checkbox1 -> (store value of this checkbox lets say in m_check1)

In Tab2 you should have another variable m_check1_val which will hold value for Checkbox1.

as soon as you click on tab2, you have to initialise Tab2 -> m_check1_val.

and then you can use m_check1_val to set value of checkbox in Tab2